# Quando clico no botão a resposta se sobrepõe a anterior ao invés de substituir e a cor adicionada ao botão não desativa quando clico em outro botão

Tags: javascript

1 - Quando clico no botão do número da tabuada para mostrá-la, as respostas das tabuadas ficam sobre a outra, eu quero que a anterior desapareça para ficar apenas a nova solicitação.
2 - Eu gostaria de deixar o botão com outra cor quando ativo, mas eu consigo apenas ativá-lo e quando escolho outro número o botão anterior continua com a classe active.

Ao escolher o botão da tabuada que gostaria que aparecesse apenas a nova tabuada.
Ao clicar no botão da tabuada escolhida eu gostaria que o botão ficasse com a classe active e quando escolher outro ativar a classe nele.

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn1")
const btn2 = document.querySelector(".btn2")
const btn3 = document.querySelector(".btn3")
const btn4 = document.querySelector(".btn4")
const btn5 = document.querySelector(".btn5")
const btn6 = document.querySelector(".btn6")
const btn7 = document.querySelector(".btn7")
const btn8 = document.querySelector(".btn8")
const btn9 = document.querySelector(".btn9")
const btn10 = document.querySelector(".btn10")

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn")

const tabuada = document.querySelector("#tabuada")

btn1.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn1)
})

btn2.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   resultado(btn2)
})

btn3.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn3)
 })

 btn4.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn4)
 })

btn5.addEventListener("click", () =>{

   resultado(btn5)
})

btn6.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn6)
 })

 btn7.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn7)
 })

 btn8.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn8)
 })

 btn9.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn9)
 })

 btn10.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    resultado(btn10)
 })

 /*Função que calcula a tabuada e apresenta na tela*/
function resultado(btns){
    let num = Number(btns.innerHTML)
    
    let tab = ""

    for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        tab = num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i + "\n"
        tabuada.textContent += tab
        }

      /*Botão que seria para ativar a classe .active para mudar 
      o background do botão quando ativo */  
      btns.classList.add("active")     
        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Tabuada</title>
</head>
<body>

    <main>
        <button class="btn btn1" id="">1</button>
        <button class="btn btn2" id="">2</button>
        <button class="btn btn3" id="">3</button>
        <button class="btn btn4" id="">4</button>
        <button class="btn btn5" id="">5</button>
        <button class="btn btn6" id="">6</button>
        <button class="btn btn7" id="">7</button>
        <button class="btn btn8" id="">8</button>
        <button class="btn btn9" id="">9</button>
        <button class="btn btn10" id="">10</button>
    </main>

    <pre id="tabuada"></pre>
    

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O problema está na função resultado, em nenhum momento você remove o texto gerado no for. Para resolver isso apenas use o código `tabuada.textContent = ""` antes do for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo demonstrando com uma das muitas maneiras de resolver os problemas relatados. Repare que com um simples loop **for** e executando o `click` dinamicamente, já conseguimos eliminar as 10 constantes que armazenavam os botões, deixando o código mais limpo. Sobre os problemas:

> 1 - Aparecer apenas os resultados referentes ao número do botão clicado

Como já comentado, basta esvaziar o conteúdo da variável que mostra o resultado anterior e preencher com o novo valor.

> 2 - Destacar o botão clicado com a classe active

Criei uma função que remove o estilo da classe active de todos os botões e a executa antes de adicionar a classe para o botão clicado.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")      // O All pega todos o botões
const tabuada = document.querySelector("#tabuada")

function calcula(btns) {
  let num = Number(btns.innerHTML)

  let tab = ""
  tabuada.textContent = ""                         // limpa o texto
  removeActive()                                   // remove a classe active

  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    tab = num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i + "\n"
    tabuada.textContent += tab
  }

  btns.classList.add("active")
}

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {             // percorre os botões
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", () => {         // pega o click do botão
    calcula(btn[i])                                // executa o calculo
  })
}

function removeActive() {
  for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].classList.remove("active")
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button class="btn btn1" id="">1</button>
  <button class="btn btn2" id="">2</button>
  <button class="btn btn3" id="">3</button>
  <button class="btn btn4" id="">4</button>
  <button class="btn btn5" id="">5</button>
  <button class="btn btn6" id="">6</button>
  <button class="btn btn7" id="">7</button>
  <button class="btn btn8" id="">8</button>
  <button class="btn btn9" id="">9</button>
  <button class="btn btn10" id="">10</button>
</main>

<pre id="tabuada"></pre>
```

Comment: Muito obg pela ajuda, utente, eu queria fazer esse loop com os botões mas eu não lembrava por ser iniciante, mt obg pela ajuda e explicação, deixarei salvo para os futuros projetos.

Comment: Opa por nada, tmj!

Answer (score -2):

Você está adicionando ao DOM a tabuada de uma forma com que ela não é substituida pela anterior no click, e somando com a anterior, fazendo com que o bloco só aumente, por conta do "tabuada.textContent += tab", para substituir a anterior, tire o sinal de +, deixando somente o =, "tabuada.textContent = tab"

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obg pela dica, Leonardo!